# What is better way to update SQL Server database using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, linq

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Linq-to-SQL.

I have this method to update one row in the database after checking some conditions.

I wrote it in two ways. Which one is faster and less resource intensive? (SQL query, CPU count...)

Query #1:

In this one I used `IEnumerable`

```
internal static bool CheckSecretCodeLoginkError(String License, String SecretCode, DataClasses1DataContext db)
{
    IEnumerable<User> user = db.Users.Where(a => a.Licensekey == License).Select(a => a);

    if (SecretCode != user.First().SecretCode && !user.First().SkipSecretCode)
    {
        if (user.First().LastSecretChangeDate > DateTime.UtcNow - TimeToPreventSecretCodeChange)
        {
            //secret error
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //no error
            //update secret code and last change
            user.First().LastSecretChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            user.First().SecretCode = SecretCode;
            db.SubmitChanges();

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Query #2:

```
internal static bool CheckSecretCodeLoginkError(String License, String SecretCode, DataClasses1DataContext db)
{
    User user = db.Users.Where(a => a.Licensekey == License).Single();

    if (SecretCode != user.SecretCode && !user.SkipSecretCode)
    {
        if (user.LastSecretChangeDate > DateTime.UtcNow - TimeToPreventSecretCodeChange)
        {
            //secret error
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //no error
            //update secret code and last change
            db.Users.Where(a => a.Licensekey == License).Select(a => a).First().LastSecretChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            db.Users.Where(a => a.Licensekey == License).Select(a => a).First().SecretCode = SecretCode;

            db.SubmitChanges();

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not measure it yourself?

Comment: I'll delete my answer and leave a comment here: You can see for yourself the SQL generated by Linq to SQL http://stackoverflow.com/a/17092821/397817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use query #2 - with an adaption:

```
internal static bool CheckSecretCodeLoginkError(String License, String SecretCode, DataClasses1DataContext db)
{
    // you store a reference in "user" here.....
    User user = db.Users.Where(a => a.Licensekey == License).Single();

    if (SecretCode != user.SecretCode && !user.SkipSecretCode)
    {
        if (user.LastSecretChangeDate > DateTime.UtcNow - TimeToPreventSecretCodeChange)
        {
            //secret error
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //no error
            //update secret code and last change

            // **REUSE** that reference you stored above!! 
            // Don't call .Where(...).Select(....).First() again!
            user.LastSecretChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            user.SecretCode = SecretCode;

            db.SubmitChanges();

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You're storing the single user you found at the beginning of the method in `user` - why are you calling the whole messy LINQ expression again when updating?!?! Just **use that reference** `user` that you already have!